# How can a foor loop with an array index be 3x slower then a switch case into a function that does the same thing?

Tags: c, switch-statement, function-pointers, benchmarking, control-flow

I was benchmarking function pointers vs switch case statements in quick-bench and got the expected result. Function pointers are slower than switch case. But I wanted to remove the operation from the equation and get just the cost of the control flow. Thats when I tried a third implementation thats just a foor loop with an array index. To my suprise it was the slowest of all of them. How can the simplest option that has all the information easily avaible be the slowest?

Settings on quick-bench: (Clang 16.0, C++20, O3)
[quick-bench result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1y3CQ.png)

Snippet SwitchCase:

```
unsigned state1(unsigned *state, unsigned *counter, unsigned var)
{
  if(0 == (var % 89))
  {
    *state = 2;
    *counter += 1;
    return var;
  }

  return var -1;
}

...

unsigned int myInt = numberOfTries;
unsigned int state = 1;
unsigned int counter = 0;

while (0 != myInt)
{      
  switch (state)
  {
    case 1:
      myInt = state1(&state, &counter, myInt);
      break;   
...

    case 10:
      myInt = state10(&state, &counter, myInt);
      break;
  }
}
```

Snippet ForLoopMod:

```
unsigned int myArr[] = { 89, 83, 79, 73, 71, 67, 61, 59, 53, 47 };
unsigned int myArrIndex = 0;
unsigned int myInt = numberOfTries;
unsigned int counter = 0;

while (0 != myInt)
{
  if (0 == (myInt % myArr[myArrIndex]))
  {
    counter++;
    myArrIndex++;
    myArrIndex %= 10;
  }
  else
  {
    myInt--;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess that `myInt % myArr[myArrIndex]` is a problem. The "modulo non-constant" is a very slow operation on modern CPUs.

Comment: Related: [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935) explains why `var % 89 == 0` is *not* as slow as runtime-variable division.  Also, if there's a pattern to the states, modern IT-TAGE branch prediction may learn it well enough to achieve a pretty good prediction rate.  (Check with `perf stat ./a.out`)

Comment: Actually, modern GCC and clang use even better tricks for divisibility tests like `var % 89 == 0` than are known for `var % 89` or `var / 89` in general.  https://godbolt.org/z/6cW31Kcsn See [Fast divisibility tests (by 2,3,4,5,.., 16)?](//stackoverflow.com/a/49264279)  .  So yeah, I concur with @tstanisl.  32-bit `div` isn't *as* slow a 64-bit `div` on Intel Skylake-family and earlier, but it's at least 23 cycle latency on Skylake, similar on Zen 2 and earlier.  https://uops.info/.  vs. the divisibility test with a constant costing just `imul`/`cmp`, so 1/clock throughput, not a bottleneck

Comment: C++ or C? It might matter.

Comment: Correction, my last comment implied `div` latency would be the important thing.  But you're branching on it and the new `myArrIndex` doesn't have a data dependency on the `%` result.  So `div` *throughput* is the relevant thing, not latency.  On Skylake and later, that's one per 6 cycles for 32-bit integers.  (The div/sqrt unit is partially pipelined so throughput is better than latency, but it's not fully pipelined.)

Comment: Looking at code explorer, the for-loop version uses `div` and `imul` and the switch-case uses `imul` and `lea`. I though that through compiler "magic" it could produce the same code but that would probably be the worlds best loop-unrolling algorithm. So the problem was that the compiler was not able to optimise away the `div` instruction. Thanks for the help!